# coming the issues of auto layouts in the console

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, autolayout

hai i am trying the auto layout concepts,here i am getting the more issues in console,can anybody tell me how to solve this

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faeb358e200 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7faeb35834b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7faeb35832c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faeb358e390 UILabel:0x7faeb358a1e0'Welcome to'.leading == UIView:0x7faeb35832c0.leadingMargin + 46>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faeb358e4d0 UIImageView:0x7faeb3585ab0.leading == UILabel:0x7faeb358a1e0'Welcome to'.leading + 28>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faeb358e520 UIImageView:0x7faeb3585ab0.leading == UIImageView:0x7faeb35834b0.leading + 90>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faeb358e390 UILabel:0x7faeb358a1e0'Welcome to'.leading == UIView:0x7faeb35832c0.leadingMargin + 46>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-12-23 16:30:57.326 Aaja[11268:148329] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

this issue is coming 10 times repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

From this error you have...

```
|[ImageView-b0]

|-46-[Label-e0]

-(+28)-[ImageView-b0]
[Label-e0]
i.e. |-74-[ImageView-b0] //this conflicts the first one.

[ImageView-b0]
-(+90)-[ImageView-b0]
```

These are the different constraints shown in the error.

It looks like a bit of a mess. You have zero spacing between the image view and the super view. You then have 46 spacing between the label and the super view.

But then you try to align the left edges of the label and image view with a difference of 28.

You then have an additional problem which I don't quite understand. You are telling it the align the leading edge of the image view with itself but with a difference. This will never be able to work.

It is basically telling you that it can't make all of the constraints work because they conflict each other and so it has to break some of them.

Comment: how to resolve this issues,i am very confusing in auto layouts